# To determine the values of constants for which the function is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(x+ iy) = x^3 +a x^2 y+b x y^2+c y^3$ is analytic in the complex plane only if :

- **A**. $a=3i$ , $b= -3$, $c=-i$.
- **B**. $a= 3$ , $b= -3i$ , $c=1$
- **C**. $a=-3$  , $b=3i$  ,$c =-1$
- **D**. $a= 3$ , $b= i$ ,    $c=-i$.

I know the first condition for a function to be analytic in complex plane is that it should be defined at every point in the complex plane . 
Now the function dont have any denominator as I would have equated it to zero.

Please help.

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Riemann equations ?

Comment: In any case, plugging in the values of option A results in $f(z)=z^3$, which is of course analytic.

Comment: @SoumyaSinha And if you know that a complex analytic function vanishing on the real numbers is identically zero (so that $f$ is determined by its values when $y=0$), you know that everything other than A must be incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to verify the Cauchy-Riemann equations for ecah of these cases, since $f$ is a plynomial, it is necessarely differentiable, so you just have to verify these equations.
For example for the first case you have :

$$f(x,y)=x^3+3ix^2y-3xy^2-iy^3$$
So we let $u(x,y)=x^3-3xy^2$ and $v(x,y)=3x^2y-y^3$, and we have :
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} =3x^2-3y^2= \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} =-6xy=  -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

The Cauchy-Riemann equations are verified, and $f$ and is differentiable as a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$. So $f$ is analytic.

You can do the same for the other cases.